# startActivityForResult closes immediately

Tags: java, android, firebase, appcompatactivity, startactivityforresult

I am developing a chat application, with the option to send pictures and files. 
The problem is, that when I click on the button to start the startActivityForResult method, the screen turns white for half a second and returns to where I was.
I tried this on the android emulator and works fine, but if I try it on my Xiaomi phone doesn't work (it worked weeks before though).

For that I use the following code:

```
public void onPickPhoto(View view) {
    if (checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(context)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Chat_PrevisualizarArchivo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
public boolean checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(final Context context) {
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                showDialog("External storage", context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public void showDialog(final String msg, final Context context, final String permission) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
    alertBuilder.setMessage(msg + " permission is necessary");
    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                            new String[] { permission },
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (!(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                Toast.makeText(Chat.this, R.string.permiso_lectura_denegado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (!(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                Toast.makeText(Chat.this, R.string.permiso_escritura_denegado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                    grantResults);
    }
}
```

That starts a new activity. In the onCreate method of that activity I have the startActivityForResult.

```
public class Chat_PrevisualizarArchivo extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lay_preview_file);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(data != null) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedFile = data.getData();
                if (selectedFile != null) {
                    filePath = getPath(Chat_PrevisualizarArchivo.this, selectedFile);
                }
                String ext = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("."), filePath.length());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've read that this could be because of the activity launch mode, here is my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Chat"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Chat_PrevisualizarArchivo"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".Chat"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Chat" />
    </activity>
```

The log when I press the button:

```
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:535826
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 5276
      Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 798871
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), 
Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=5276, 
firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Chat, 
firebase_screen_id(_si)=4620370960915656203}]
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:535898
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), 
Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=Chat, 
firebase_previous_id(_pi)=4620370960915656203, 
firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Chat_PrevisualizarArchivo, 
firebase_screen_id(_si)=4620370960915656205}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
      Connection attempt already in progress
      Activity resumed, time: 798938
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@22de4a86 
time:535977
V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 88
      Activity paused, time: 798959
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), 
Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, 
firebase_previous_class(_pc)=Chat_PrevisualizarArchivo, 
firebase_previous_id(_pi)=4620370960915656205, 
firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Chat, 
firebase_screen_id(_si)=4620370960915656203}]
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3b9d55a7 
time:536254
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 799233
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 30379
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 829611
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), 
Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=30379, 
firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Chat, 
firebase_screen_id(_si)=4620370960915656203}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Connected to remote service
```

Looking at the log I don't know if it has something to do with Firebase, which I use for the messaging part of the app.

Any help would be apreciated, thanks!

Comment: try this `Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);`

Comment: Same result, closes immediately.

Comment: have you given runtime permission

Comment: Yes. I edited my asnwer. Check the first chunk of code.

Comment: You are trying to access media, you need add file provider in your manifest and same in your activity.

Comment: If I change to `Intent.ACTION_PICK`, the app chooser opens and works fine. The problem seems to be `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` but what I don't understand is why the log doesn't show any crash errors.